# How to set a default selected value in a form select in Kendo UI?

Tags: javascript, select, kendo-ui

I have this select:

```
<select name="type" required data-bind="source: types, value: model.type" data-template="typeTemplate"></select>
```

and a template:

```
<script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="typeTemplate">
    <option value="#: name #" #if (name =='default' ) { # selected # } #>#: name #</option>
</script>
```

This will create a select that contains a a few options and one named `default` with a `selected` property, but the select shows empty rather then the default option.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the data-text-field and data-value-field attributes on your select statement. Here is an example:

```
<select data-text-field="name" data-value-field="id" 
   data-template="optionTemplate"   
   data-bind="source: users, value: selectedUserId"></select>

 <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="optionTemplate">
    <option data-bind="value:id,text:name"></option>
 </script>
```

In this example, there is an observable array called users [{ id: 1, name: 'dave'}, { id: 2, 'james'}] on the view model.  There is also a field called selectedUserId on the view model with a value of 1, which is a number that would corresponding to dave's id in this case.